# Anti-aliasing in allegro 5

Tags: c++, antialiasing, allegro, allegro5

How do I make allegro 5 use anti-aliasing when drawing? I need diagonal lines to appear smooth. Currently, they are only lines of shaded pixels, and the edges look hard.

Comment: See my answer for how to enable it and the limitations involved. As an aside, if you don't need realtime performance for a game, you could also hook into libcairo to draw nice looking vector graphics. It's extremely simple to hook it into Allegro, but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable anti aliasing for the primitives:

```
// before creating the display:
al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1, ALLEGRO_SUGGEST);
al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_SAMPLES, 8, ALLEGRO_SUGGEST);

display = al_create_display(640, 480);
```

Note that anti-aliasing will only work for primitives drawn directly to the back buffer. It will not work anywhere else.

On OpenGL, your card must support the [ARB_multisample](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multisample.txt) extension.

To check if it was enabled (when using ALLEGRO_SUGGEST):

```
if (al_get_display_option(display, ALLEGRO_SAMPLE_BUFFERS)) {
   printf("With multisampling, level %i\n",
     al_get_display_option(display, ALLEGRO_SAMPLES));
}
else {
   printf("Without multisampling.\n");
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't appear to be working. Will it work with the function al_draw_filled_rectangle?

Comment: I think it should. If it doesn't work with `al_draw_line()`, then it's definitely not enabled. (Drawing a diagonal line is an easy check.) You should be able to use `al_get_display_option()` after the display is created to check if the option was set. Or if you switch the `ALLEGRO_SAMPLE_BUFFERS` line to `ALLEGRO_REQUIRED` and no display is created, then your card / drivers must not support it.

Comment: I used `al_get_display_option()` to check both `ALLEGRO_SAMPLE_BUFFERS` and `ALLEGRO_SAMPLES`, and they both have the values I assigned them, but when I run `al_draw_line()`, its still making hard edges. Is there anything else I need to enable?

Comment: No, it should work. Try the ex_multisample program that comes with Allegro for an additional test.

Comment: Well, that didn't work either. Anything else that might be wrong?

Comment: If multisampling is reportedly enabled and ex_multisample doesn't work, there there's either a bug with Allegro's detection or with your card/driver itself. Are you using OpenGL or D3D? On Windows, it defaults to D3D, but you can request OpenGL. Other platforms only support OpenGL. If you cannot get it to work, then I would post a small bug report on http://www.allegro.cc/forums along with details of your environment (OS / video card / Allegro version, etc).

Comment: @Jcubed. It is possible that Allegro doesn't call `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)`; this is required to activate multisampled rendering.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options: line smoothing or multisampling.

You can activate line smoothing by using glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH). Note that Allegro 5 may reset this when you draw lines through Allegro.

The other alternative is to create a multisampled display. This must be done before calling `al_create_display`. The way to do it goes something like this:

```
al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1, ALLEGRO_REQUIRE);
al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_SAMPLES, #, ALLEGRO_SUGGEST);
```

The # above should be the number of samples to use. How many? That's implementation-dependent, and Allegro doesn't help. That's why I used ALLEGRO_SUGGEST rather than REQUIRE for the number of samples. The more samples you use, the better quality you get. 8 samples might be a good value that's supported on most hardware.